# Getting an error when uninstalling Oracle Analytics Publisher Desktop - The installation source for this product is not available

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-registry, uninstall

Oracle Analytics Publisher Desktop has been installed and uninstalled 2 times.  Something must have gone wrong the last time I uninstalled it.  The program is listed in Control Panel and in the Uninstall Programs lists, yet the program files are all deleted.

When I attempt to uninstalled using Control Panel or Add or remove programs, I get this error:

> “The installation source for this product is not available. Verify that the source exists and that you can access it. C:\windows\installer\4032c.msi.”

I cannot see that "installer" folder from file manager even though the option to see Hidden Items is checked. I can list the file the CMD.  Therefore, the source does exist, and I can access it. I suspect that my Windows registry is corrupted.

I have tried performing a System Restore but no affect. What should my next solution be? Manually fixing the Registry was going to be my last option.

Comment: The installer is missing so you will have to reinstall the software and hopefully you won’t have to manually uninstall it in order to reinstall it. Your registry absolutely is not corrupt, the windows registry, has protection against such corruption. It’s very very difficult to actually corrupt the windows registry.

Comment: There are third-party applications that clean up the list of installed applications but in my mind that’s unnecessary when reinstalling the software then uninstalling the software will often resolve this very common configuration problem

Comment: When attempting to reinstall the application I get the following error:  
**Another version of this product is already installed. 
Installation of this version cannot continue. to configure or
remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove
Programs on the Control Panel.
{5FCAFAC0-4327-4320-9ED4-7846FE4E30DD}**
@Ramhound - Perhaps the third-party application to clean up is the next step?

Comment: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\(Wow6432Node)\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ 5FCAFAC0-4327-4320-9ED4-7846FE4E30DD** is where the installer is checked (or the equivalent 64-bit registry

Comment: I did not know how to use the HKEY information above, so I passed the information on to a college of mine.  He was able to use it to get rid of the program and thus allow him to reinstall it.  @Ramhound How should we word this for a complete solution, or do we just leave it all in comments?

Comment: You should identify the actual key that was deleted and submit an answer.  I just didn't have a Windows machine in front of me when I made that comment that had access to the registry editor.  I still don't have access to one.